# Newtonsoft.Json.dll conflicts between Visual Studio 12.0 Blend and MVC 5 web project VS 2013

Tags: json.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a asp.net mvc 5 project in VS2013, I updated the nuget packages of everything to latest

then I run into this error

```
Error   2   The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' and '{path to my project}\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

Does anyone else run into this.

Answer (score 21):

I got that error because I had an additional

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
    <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Owin">
    <HintPath>..\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

in my Web.csproj directly below the usual references which already contained the correct reference to the latest Newtonsoft.Json.dll. In VS only the reference to the newer assembly was shown.

Solution was: I moved the valid Owin reference to the main references ItemGroup and deleted the outdated Newtonsoft.Json.dll reference (manually editing the csproj file).

Cause of the error message: On my machine the HintPath of the old Newtonsoft.Json.dll did not exist, therefor MSBuild was looking elsewhere and took the Blend version.

(BTW: To see why and where MSBuild is looking for a certain assembly use TOOLS -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> und set the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting to "Detailed" and rebuild the project.)

Comment: Im confused here. I found two references in my csproj file. I removed the older version. There was no change.

Comment: Worked for me too. Respect!

Comment: Great job and how did you figure it out?

Comment: Great job.. Saved my day

Answer (score 4):

I don't use Blend at all so I renamed the Blend Newtonsoft.Json.dll to "Newtonsoft.Json.dll.bak". This was mentioned as a work around in the [Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816725/visual-studio-referencing-dll-in-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-visual-studio-12-0-blend-directory-incorrectly) by Marcus. Marcus continues, saying that Blend may not use Newtonsoft.Json.dll much, so even if you use Blend it's possible that this fix will not affect your work.

Comment: I looked at the referenced dll path it is pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll instead of the packages folder, is there a way to modify this path?

Comment: ya that's the file i added .bak to, you can't change the path - weird bug. Upvote that Connect bug, say you can reproduce it, and add it to your watch list.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. This may work, but it's wrong as it could have unknown consequences. The correct way is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21776577/103302

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is in @blueling's answer, which I will quote:

> Cause of the error message: On my machine the HintPath of the old
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll did not exist, therefor MSBuild was looking
>   elsewhere and took the Blend version.

I just wanted to put this as a separate answer to make it easier to find since people may not read his/her whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue mainly occur while using Visual Studio community. the same issue you wont find on Visual Studio professional.

I had this problem because, I was using profession community.

It occur because, while compiling project, then it will takes the reference from both locations one is from
1). "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

2).  And other is from your solution/project reference. in this case both versions are different

and it gives

```
The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' and '{path to my project}\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

**The only way to get project to compile is to rename the NewtonSoft dll in the Blend folder.**